# HTML/CSS - Full Page Overlay for Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I am having some trouble creating a full page overlay to recognize dragging + dropping. If a user drags a file from their computer over the page, dropping it anywhere will trigger an upload. However, I'm having trouble getting a full page overlay which is recognized when the file is dropped and doesn't block any hover elements on the page. Here is my current code.

HTML:

```
<div id = 'dropZone'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#dropZone
{
    background: gray;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: .8;
}
```

JS that recognizes the drop:

```
var dropZone = document.getElementById('dropZone');
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V37cE/

Comment: Delete the spaces between surrounding your `=` sign in your html.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by: "...when the file is dropped and doesn't block any hover elements on the page."

Comment: I need a div to recognize when the file is dropped on the page. If the div is set to be above all the other elements, it acts like a shield, so no effects work (hovering and clicking).

Comment: It's possible you paste your result because i have this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the drop zone id to the  tag, which covers the full page.

Comment: are you missing 'body' somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

for such overlay, to be displayed only when dragging content, you should handle the dragenter and dragleave event on different elements:

```
<body>
 <div>...</div>
 <div id="myDropZone" ondragenter="handleDragEnter" style="z-index: 1">

   <div id="myDropOverlay" ondragleave="handleDragLeave" onDrop="handleDrop" hidden style="z-index: 2">
     Drop your file here
   </div>

   <div>
     content covered by the drop zone overlay while dragging
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

You then hide/show the overlay in js:

```
function handleDragEnter(event) {
  showMyDropZoneOverlay();
}
function handleDragLeave(event) {
  hideMyDropZoneOverlay();
}
function handleDrop(event) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should help. Here's a [great tutorial](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/filedrag/1/index.html) on the HTML5 File Drag & Drop API. And here's the [w3.org documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/dnd.html#dnd) for the API.